# SQL getting text from value

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

have values 'abcde:fg' and 'abcde' i need to remove the ':fg' from the first value. Using SQL so far i have used the substring function to remove the '12:' from the value '12:abcde:fg'. having an issue with the :fg' part now. Any help is appreciated. thanks! however some values are 'AA:12:abcde:fg' how would i edit this script to still return the 'abcde' part of this string?

Comment: Please give use the sample code you have tried so far and what SQL-dialect (server) you are using

Comment: substring(col,8,15) returns  'abcde:fg'   SQLServer 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go. Haven't tested it but should be something like that:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(50) = '12:abcde:fg'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, charindex(':',@string) + 1, charindex(':',@string,charindex(':',@string) + 1) - (charindex(':',@string) + 1))
```

Comment: receive error substring function requires 3 arguments

Comment: thanks! however some values are 'AA:12:abcde:fg' how would i edit this script to still return the 'abcde' part of this string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MS SQL, and that you want to remove everything from the before and including the first :, and then removing everything after the next one:

Another "simple" method would be to wrap substring twice, the first one (inner) keeps everything after the first : and the second (outer) keeps everything before the second (now first after the old-first was removed)

guessing your field is called MyField:

select substring(substring(MyField,0,charindex(':',MyField)),charindex(':',substring(MyField,0,charindex(':',MyField)))+1)

Comment: using SQL server 2012